# Scroll ListView change

Tags: android, listview

Tell me, please, why in one listview scroll continuously changes from item to item?
How to make it permanent?

```
<ListView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/WallList" 
        android:layout_margin="10dp" 
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent" 
        android:dividerHeight="20dp" 
        android:padding="10dp" 
        android:fadeScrollbars="false" 
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"/>
```

Custom listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:background="@drawable/listbackground" 
              android:padding="10dp"> 

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text1" 
              android:layout_width="match_parent" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
              android:textColor="#000" 
              android:textSize="15dp" 
              android:text="ghbd"/> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mP0OT.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHu0z.png

Comment: are you trying to make a listview which does not changes on scroll.Clarify yourself in detail or pls try to explain senario

Comment: It because items have not the same height... play with http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setSmoothScrollbarEnabled%28boolean%29

Comment: does your problem got resolved?

Comment: Selvin, thank you. it works.
But I want to make a smooth scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your custom listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text1" 
          android:layout_width="match_parent" 
          android:layout_height="75dp" 
          android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
          android:textColor="#000" 
          android:textSize="15dp" 
          android:text="ghbd"/>
```

Set textview height to a fixed size ' android:layout_height="75dp" '. That way they won't stretch abnormally.

Comment: But I can't set a fixed height, the text can be a great

Comment: Can you then be a bit precise as to what you want to archieve?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/uAQ9Lcg.jpg  - Now, smooth, textview of different heights (this app for vk.com, news activity)